# Cloning Android's tegra kernel, it's empty?

Tags: android, git, linux-kernel

I followed the steps on 
http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html
 in order to look at the kernel sources.

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra.git
Cloning into 'tegra'...
remote: Total 2219519 (delta 1857594), reused 2219519 (delta 1857594)
Receiving objects: 100% (2219519/2219519), 436.09 MiB | 3.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1857594/1857594), done.
```

Now, this is very strange... the project is **empty**

`git log` shows the following:

```
$ git log
commit a89a700fada233480530e4741cca876cfdd4eb9c
Author: Jean-Baptiste Queru <jbq@google.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 15 14:46:15 2011 -0800

    empty commit
```

what's going on, where are the sources ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'm answering my own question.
Apparently, the main branch is empty, and the **contents is available on other branches.**

```
git branch -a
```

shows few branches. I checked-out one of them and I got to the code.